# Communication between proccesses in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a library that is being used in android apps. I found out that in cases when the app has multi processes my library will have a ton of problems. Is there a way to know if a instance of my library is already running in a different process so I don't start a new one ?

Comment: I believe you need to look into `Singleton` pattern.

Comment: Singletons will not help, there can be many singleton instances in different processes

Answer (score 0):

In general, no. Your library may provide a method that allows you to check for this, but there isn't a way to know what libraries another app is running at runtime.